# Cannot display Array in Flatlist format

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Long story short, I'm trying to create a list of video-games. I have an autocomplete library that matches a game title with what I write in my input box.

I added a button that onPress triggers a function that pushes what I have in 'query'( which is what I am writing in my input box) into an array called myGamesArray

Then I'm trying to display myGamesArray in list form using Flatlist. But for some reason it is not showing up.

My code is a little messy because the solution I found to place a button next to my input box was by changing the flex direction to 'row'

I added a button right below the FlatList just to check if it would display underneath the inputbox (which it does) but for some reason the flatlist does not

Here's all my App.js

```js
/*This is an example of AutoComplete Input/ AutoSuggestion Input*/
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import react in our code.
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View, Image, Alert, FlatList } from 'react-native';
//import all the components we are going to use.
import Autocomplete from 'react-native-autocomplete-input';
import { Button, List, Container, ListItem, Header } from 'native-base';
//import Autocomplete component


//Demo base API to get the data for the Autocomplete suggestion
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //Initialization of state
    //games will contain the array of suggestion
    //query will have the input from the autocomplete input
    this.state = {
      myGamesArray: [],
      games: [],
      query: '',
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    //First method to be called after components mount
    //fetch the data from the server for the suggestion
    fetch('https://api.rawg.io/api/games?page=1&platforms=18', {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
          "x-rapidapi-host": "rawg-video-games-database.p.rapidapi.com",
          "x-rapidapi-key": "495a18eab9msh50938d62f12fc40p1a3b83jsnac8ffeb4469f"
        }
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        const { results: games } = json;
        this.setState({ games });
        //setting the data in the games state
      });
  }

  findGame(query) {
    //method called everytime when we change the value of the input
    if (query === '') {
      //if the query is null then return blank
      return [];
    }
 
    const { games } = this.state;
    //making a case insensitive regular expression to get similar value from the game json
    const regex = new RegExp(`${query.trim()}`, 'i');

    //return the filtered game array according the query from the input
    return games.filter(game => game.name.search(regex) >= 0);
  }  

AddItemsToArray=()=>{
 
      //Adding Items To Array.
     this.state.myGamesArray.push( this.state.query.toString() )
 
      // Showing the complete Array on Screen Using Alert (just to check if it's infact inside the array)
      Alert.alert(this.state.myGamesArray.toString());
 
  }
 
  render() {
    const { query } = this.state;
    const games = this.findGame(query);
    const comp = (a, b) => a.toLowerCase().trim() === b.toLowerCase().trim();
 
    return (
      <View>
               
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Autocomplete
          style={styles.autocompleteContainer1}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          //data to show in suggestion
          data={games.length === 1 && comp(query, games[0].name) ? [] : games}
          //default value if you want to set something in input
          defaultValue={query}
          /*onchange of the text changing the state of the query which will trigger
          the findGame method to show the suggestions*/
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
          placeholder="Selecione os jogos que voce quer receber!"
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            //you can change the view you want to show in suggestion from here
            //I GET ERROR WHEN TRYING TO ERASE (PS4) IN TEXT BOX ***NEED TO CHECK THIS
            <View style={styles.iconContainer} >
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query: item.name})}
              style={styles.itemContainer} >
              <View>
              <Image
                style={styles.profilepic}
                  source={{uri: item.background_image}}
                />
               </View>
              <Text style={styles.itemText}>
                {item.name} (PS4)
              </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          )}
          />
          <Button
            style={styles.addButton}
            icon='plus'
            title="Click Here To Add Value To Array"
            onPress={() => this.AddItemsToArray()}
          />
          <View style={styles.descriptionContainer}>
          
            {games.length > 0 ? (
              //Text inside input box
              <Text style={styles.infoText}>{this.state.query}</Text>
            ) : (
              <Text style={styles.infoText}>{this.state.query}</Text>                    
              )
          } 
          </View>  
      </View>

      <View style={styles.container2}> 
          <Button
          full></Button> 
        
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.myGamesArray}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <ListItem>{item}</ListItem>
            )}
          />
          
    </View>  
      
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection:'row',
    padding: 16,
    marginTop: 40,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  container2: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 100,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  autocompleteContainer1: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderColor: '#7843FF',
    height: 50,
    width:300
  },
  itemContainer: {
    flex:1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderWidth:0.5,
    borderColor: '#7843FF',
    paddingVertical: 5,
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingRight: 60
  },
  addButton: {
  width:50,
  height: 50,
  borderColor: '#7843FF',
  borderWidth: 0.5,
  backgroundColor: '#fff'
  },
  descriptionContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius: 10,
    color: '#fff',
    borderColor: '#7843FF'
  },
  itemText: {
    fontSize: 15,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight:30,
    marginVertical:10,
    color: '#000',
    textAlign: 'left',
    justifyContent: 'center'
    
  },
  infoText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#000',
  },
  profilepic: {
    flex: 3,
    height: 60,
    width: 60,
    marginLeft:10,
    borderRadius: 100,
  },
});
export default App;
```

Comment: `myGamesArray` isn't in react state or props and never changes object reference, react components only rerender when state/props update. The flat list always receives the same `myGamesArray` reference so it won't rerender.

Comment: thanks for the tip, Drew. I updated it but still it does not display the flatlist

Comment: `this.state.myGamesArray.push( this.state.query.toString() )` is a state mutation, need to *actually* do a state update and return a new array object reference.

Comment: ok...so something this.setState(myGamesArray.push(this.state.query.toString())) and then return myGamesArray?

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

`this.state.myGamesArray.push(this.state.query.toString())` is a state mutation. You need to *actually* do a state update and return a new array object reference.

## Solution

Use a functional state update to access the previous state object, and shallow copy the old array into a new array reference and append the new query value to the end.

Also, logging or otherwise trying to reference the updated state right after enqueueing the update won't work like that, state is const and updated *between* render cycles so it'll enclose the *current* state.

```
AddItemsToArray = () => {
  //Adding Items To Array.
  this.setState(prevState => {
      const { myGamesArray, query } = prevState;
      return {
        myGamesArray: [...myGamesArray, query.toString()],
      };
    },
    // Use setState callback to alert with the updated state
    () => {
      // Showing the complete Array on Screen Using Alert (just to check if it's in fact inside the array)
      Alert.alert(this.state.myGamesArray.toString());
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I could not come to this conclusion myself. But for some reason my flatlist is still not being updated with the items in myGamesArray

Comment: @Enzovt This could be caused by a react key issue. Think you could create a running minimal & reproducible example in an [expo snack](https://expo.io/) that we could debug? Also, sometimes when distilling a problem down to a minimal example the issue becomes apparent.

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/cJnqQFXu! I have this right here but It doesn't let me use Native-base

Comment: @Enzovt Looks like maybe that snack wasn't saved, it can't be found when clicking the link.

Comment: Drew, sorry for the late response. I was able to fix that issue. Now say I want to add another string variable from state to the second column of myGamesArray, how would I do that? In this case, I am storing an information in my string variable 'image' with an URL and I want to store in the second column of myGamesArray

Comment: @Enzovt That appears to be an entirely different issue, so I suggest you either (A) Answer this question/issue with your working solution and open a new SO issue with a minimal, reproducible code example, or (B) just completely edit this question for the new issue. IMO A is preferred so questions/answers are preserved. What does "the second column in `myGamesArray`" mean?